# In Odoo 8 ORM api , how to get results in reverse order using search()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-8

I try to use [`search()`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.search) to fetch data from a table in a http controller.

```
 x = obj.search(cr, uid, criteria, offset=0,limit=36,order=sortBy)
```

It returns an array containing the ids of the top 36 items ordered by `sortBy` but always in increasing order. But how to make it using decreasing order?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Search**

Takes a search [domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm-domains), returns a recordset of matching records. Can return a subset of matching records (offset and limit parameters) and be ordered (order parameter):

Syntax:

```
search(args[, offset=0][, limit=None][, order=None][, count=False])
```

Parameters:

- **args** -- A search domain. Use an empty list to match all records.
- **offset** (int) -- number of results to ignore (default: none)
- **limit** (int) -- maximum number of records to return (default: all)
- **order** (str) -- sort string
- **count** (bool) -- if True, only counts and returns the number of matching records (default: False)

**Returns**:    Returns records matching the search criteria up to limit.

**Raise AccessError**: 
if user tries to bypass access rules for read on the requested object.

You just need to search in following manner with descending order.

```
    sortBy = "field_name desc"
     x = obj.search(cr, uid, criteria, offset=0,limit=36,order=sortBy)

    ###Or you can define directly
     x = obj.search(cr, uid, criteria, offset=0,limit=36,order='field_name desc')
```

Comment: "args": [
      {
        "limit": 1,
        "model": "crm.lead"} , here limit is not working. can you help me ?\